# Understanding how bootstrap container-fluid works and how to make a section inside the container fill the entire width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on learning bootstrap and I would like to have a website with a header, a footer, and three middle columns. So far I have the header and columns, but I'm not fully understanding how to make the the footer, and I'm pretty sure I did it the wrong way, but I would like some assistance figuring it out. I tried putting it in a div and changing the width to 100 vw and I'm just not fully understanding it. The header is basically just the container fluid part on top and I made a div for the footer but the edges still are the color of the container, So I guess my question is: what is the exact purpose of container and container-fluid and how do I make the footer div take up the whole space? Thanks, Code is:

```css
    .div1 {
      background-color:red;
    }

    .div2 {
      background-color:gray;
    }

    .div3 {
      background-color:blue;
    }

    .row {
      height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    }

    #main {
      background-color: lime;
    }

    #main_head {
      height: 200px;
      color: red;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #main_foot {
      height: 200px;
      background-color: pink;
      margin: 0;
      color: red;
  }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
      <h1 id="main_head">This is a heading</h1>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 div1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 div2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 div3">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="main_foot" class="container-fluid"><h1>This is a footer</h1></div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`container-fluid` takes the full width of the screen while `container` has fixed size for each resolution.

```css
.div1 {
      background-color:red;
    }

    .div2 {
      background-color:gray;
    }

    .div3 {
      background-color:blue;
    }

    .row {
      height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    }

    #main {
      background-color: lime;
    }

    #main_head {
      height: 200px;
      color: red;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #main_foot {
      height: 200px;
      background-color: pink;
      margin: 0;
      color: red;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
    
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
      <h1 id="main_head">This is a heading</h1>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 div1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 div2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 div3">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="main_foot" class="container-fluid"><h1>This is a footer</h1></div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```